# Does apple notify you when a certificate is going to expire?

Tags: certificate, apns

Do apple notify the developer or email when a push notification is going to expired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, at 30 days, 10 days and 1 day prior to expiration date, you will receive the following email:

[image]

Comment: Is there any setup for this? I have Enterprise apple account, which is handled and created by my client. To get this expiration mail what to do? Do  I have to add my email as admin type in client apple account?

Comment: @iKT I did nothing in particular to receive these emails, I just get them!

Comment: ok. which type apple account you have? agent or admin or member? any idea?

Comment: @iKT This isn't through iTunes Connect, this [Apple Push Certificates Portal](https://identity.apple.com/pweb/)

Comment: Ok, Is there any way to get mail notification for provisioning profile expiration before 30 days.

Comment: Hi our push notification expired without any email at all. Is this still working?